# Incorrect CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS when using ProjectCapabilityManager in Unity to add entitlements to Xcode output

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm using ProjectCapabilityManager OnPostprocessBuildIOS to automate the process of enabling capabilities, "Associated Domains" specifically, and adding applinks:mydomain.xxx as an associated domain for my iOS game in Unity3d.

This is the code (with little modification to string values) that I'm using:

```
    string pbxPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(pathToBuiltProject);
    string entitlementsFileName = "myproject.entitlements";
    var entitlements = new ProjectCapabilityManager(pbxPath, entitlementsFileName, PBXProject.GetUnityTargetName());      
    entitlements.AddAssociatedDomains(new string[] { "applinks:mydomain.xxx" });
    entitlements.WriteToFile();
```

The problem is the project in Xcode will end up having two entitlement file addresses separated by an space as the value for CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS, something like:

```
myproject.entitlements Unity-iPhone/Unity-iPhone.entitlements
```

and Xcode says
Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS build setting for target "Unity-iPhone" is correct and that the file exists on disk.
If I remove any of the two files from CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS there is not an error anymore.

How should I solve this?

Comment: I've been able to fix this problem by using the same entitlements name in the code